# Can I get my iPhone SE to save photos without so much useless padding at the end?

Tags: iphone, photos

I'm writing a Jpeg/Exif parser program and it has revealed to me that the photos that come off my "iPhone SE (2nd generation)" have a ton of useless 0's at the end.  A Jpeg file is supposed to start with 0xffd8 (SOI) and end with 0xffd9 (EOI).  I've been analyzing jpg files from 10+ phones.  Most are compliant, a few Androids have ~100 bytes of "other data" past the final EOI, but my phone is the absolute worst offender.  1-3 MB of useless 0's at the end of each photo!  Multiply that by the 100's (1000's?) of photos I've uploaded over the years and that's GB's of wasted HDD space!  For 4032x3024 resolution photos, most phones average 2-3 MB file size.  Mine are 4-5 MB.

More data points: My old "iPhone SE" (1st generation) didn't have the problem. Some photos I found from an "iPhone 7" did have the problem. All the other iPhones I've tested didn't do it.  Also, firmware version doesn't matter, I've checked back through photos from various versions.

I can certainly add an option to my program to save the file with the extraneous data removed, but that doesn't address the extra space they're taking up on my phone.  Is Apple aware of this issue?  Is their some setting to address this?

Comment: Could the extra data be related to the [Live Photos](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207310)?

Comment: Good theory Allan. No, I don't have LIVE mode enabled. I enabled it and uploaded a picture - it generates a JPG and a MOV.  The JPG parses like all the others (all the worthless 0's), the MOV is the actual LIVE photo (+/- 1.5s from snapping the pic).